# Data Frame, Data Cleaning

Tags: r

I was just wondering whether there was an optimal way of solving the following problem:

I have a rather large Data Frame of daily returns for individuals firms.

```
dates  <- c("04.01.1995","05.01.1995","06.01.1995","09.01.1995","10.01.1995","11.01.1995","12.01.1995","13.01.1995")
stock1 <- rnorm(0.1,n = 3)
stock2 <- c(unlist(strsplit(rep("Na",8),split = " ")))
stock3 <- rnorm(0.1,n = 3)
stock4 <- rnorm(0.1,n = 3)
stock5 <- rnorm(0.1,n = 3)
stock6 <- rnorm(0.1,n = 3)
stock7 <- rnorm(0.1,n = 3)
stock8 <- c(unlist(strsplit(rep("Na",8),split = " ")))

cbind(dates,stock1,stock2,stock3,stock4,stock5,stock6,stock7,stock8)
```

Which looks something like this:

```
dates         stock1   stock2  stock3      stock4               stock5....              
"04.01.1995" "1.8249" "Na"     "2.7125"    "0.557280737196038"  "1.38681707010098"
```

I would like to compute the mean of each particular row, and then remove the observations/elements within the same row, below the "row-mean" or  threshold.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `mutate` to compute row-wise mean and then `select` to remove columns

Comment: df.dropna(subset=['stock.2'])

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Please provide an example of what you have vs what you want.

Comment: Sorry About that! Example provided above :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the `dplyr` package. There are plenty of introductions online, but the best is to take it [directly from Hadley](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html).

Your data is a bit messy: it would be much better to have a column for the date, a column for the stock number and a column for the value. This is easily achieved using the `gather` function from the `tidyr` package (as the name indicates, a package that specialises in cleaning messy data). Again, loads of [online resources](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/).

From there, you likely want to `group_by` company/stock and year, then `summarise` to get the average value per company and per year, then `filter` to keep only the companies that meet your criteria.

Hopefully you have enough keywords to search more effectively!

Comment: okay, because I have tried to transpose the particular rows, removing NA and then compute the mean. then removing the observations for each particular cell through a nested for-loop. Having difficulties to implement it though and maybe not the smartest solution. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Yes it is definitely not straightforward to work with data that is both vertical and horizontal. Much better to simply gather it (by calling `tidyr::gather(df, stock, return, stock.1:stock.7)` ). Then all your operations become much easier, especially if you use `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
datos =data.frame(date=c('02/01/1995','2019-01-02','2019-01-03'),
                 stock.1=c(0.1,NA,6),
                 stock.2=c(NA,7,6),
                 stock.3=c(0.4,7,1),
                 stock.4=c(0.1,7,1),
                 stock.5=c(0.2,7,1),
                 stock.6=c(0.7,7,1),
                 stock.7=c(1.2,7,1)
                        )


result <- datos[!(datos$date == "02/01/1995" & datos$stock.1==0.1 &     datos$stock.2=="NA" & datos$stock.3==0.4 & datos$stock.4==0.1 & datos$stock.5==0.2 & 
datos$stock.6==0.7 & datos$stock.7==1.2),]
```

This is the result:

```
        date stock.1 stock.2 stock.3 stock.4 stock.5 stock.6 stock.7
1 02/01/1995     0.1      NA     0.4     0.1     0.2     0.7     1.2
2 2019-01-02      NA       7     7.0     7.0     7.0     7.0     7.0
3 2019-01-03     6.0       6     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0
> result <- datos[!(datos$date == "02/01/1995" & datos$stock.1==0.1 &     datos$stock.2=="NA" & datos$stock.3==0.4 & datos$stock.4==0.1 & datos$stock.5==0.2 &     datos$stock.6==0.7 & datos$stock.7==1.2),]
> result
         date stock.1 stock.2 stock.3 stock.4 stock.5 stock.6 stock.7
NA       <NA>      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2  2019-01-02      NA       7       7       7       7       7       7
3  2019-01-03       6       6       1       1       1       1       1
```

I hope this helps!